# neovim clangd show document when hover & go to definition (not declaration)

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, clangd

I'm using some linux APIs for my study recently and had to read comments on kernel code.
But some of my vim actions doesn't work as expected.

For example, I would like to read docstring of `device_create` which is written on `drivers/base/core.c` above `device_create` definition

[image]

but Neovim hover shows comment in the corresponding header file (which is `include/linux/device.h`) where the function is declared.

[image]

Also gd (go to definition) would not go to definition but goes to declaration.

Maybe vscode behaviors can give some hints for resolving.

In VSCode, in the beginning, it shows just like the neovim does.

[image]

but gd takes me to correct definition

[image]

and once I go to the definition, the hover results as expected.

[image]

### Summary

- How can I make neovim show comments on definition when I hover (`K`) ?
- How can I make neovim go to the definition not the declaration when I `gd`?

### Environments

- neovim 0.9
- LSP: clangd
- `compile_commands.json` is created

Comment: vi/vim questions should be asked, instead, on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ Delete this one if you do (and you should)

Comment: @Rob I don't actually agree with that. Issues about clangd setup are sometimes (often?) independent of the editor. I'm a clangd maintainer and I follow and answer clangd questions on SO; I'm not going to join editor-specific SEs to follow clangd questions there.

Comment: @parkjbdev Going to the declaration instead of the definition is usually a sign of the project not being indexed, or the index not containing the file in question. Does `drivers/base/core.c` have an entry in `compile_commands.json`? If you can attach [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) those might help shed light on the problem.

Comment: @HighCommander4 I've had too many fights with mods about this and they are the ones who convinced me to tell people the vi/vim questions should be asked on the vi/vim stackexchange. I just do what the mods told me to do.

Comment: But the question is still off topic and should be closed based on the summary alone. 1) Needs focus. Too many questions and 2) Seeks recommendations for software. @HighCommander4

Comment: Fair enough. An alternative forum for clangd questions that is not editor-specific is https://github.com/clangd/clangd/discussions, @parkjbdev you can feel free to ask your question there.

Comment: Turns out that it was not Neovim's problem but with clangd as @HighCommander4 told. I'll move this thread to the clangd discussion soon. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was inspecting for this issue for a while and founded out that it was an issue in clangd parsing the linux source file.

1. move the entire project somewhere in the linux kernel source tree. (ex. under `tools` folder) - which resolves `gd`(goto definition) problem
2. if hover still shows the comment in wrong place, go to the **declaration** of the function (ex. `device_create` in my case) and remove the comment above temporarily.
3. remove `.cache` and let clangd re-index

and finally! clangd shows me the comment I wanted in the c file.

So, it turns out that clangd takes precedence in showing comments above the declaration part.

Of course, I don't think this is the best solution yet.

Maybe configuring clangd to take higher precedence on comments starting with `/**` (not `/*`) might fix this issue properly.

Please tell me if there is a way to do so.